# VSCode C# missing suggestions documentation tooltip while typing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm missing the suggestions documentation tooltip while doing C# in VSCode and having the C# Omnisharp extension installed. 
What is this tooltip called? How can I turn this on?

Current behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD9E1.png

Wanted behaviour:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdWYT.jpg

Note that I can see documentation, but only when I hover my mouse over it. Not while I'm typing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS1ft.png

```
C:\>code --list-extensions
77qingliu.sas-syntax
alexiv.vscode-angular2-files
Angular.ng-template
casualjim.theme-desertex
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer
Darfka.vbscript
eg2.tslint
esbenp.prettier-vscode
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
infinity1207.angular2-switcher
ionceflorin.copy-current-file-path
jchannon.csharpextensions
jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager
johnpapa.Angular2
ms-vscode.csharp
msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome
PKief.material-icon-theme
redhat.java
Shan.code-settings-sync
sohibe.java-generate-setters-getters
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven
vscodevim.vim
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it. Tap ctrl + space twice! after the dot (.) while typing.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

"As provided by the language service, you can see quick info for each 
method by either pressing Ctrl+Space or clicking the info icon. The 
accompanying documentation for the method will now expand to the 
side. The expanded documentation will stay so and will update as you 
navigate the list. 
**You can close this by pressing Ctrl+Space again 
or by clicking on the close icon.**"